# How can I get a new line in a textarea?

Tags: php

I have a textarea that I need to put a new line into with some dashes above. I have tried nl2br but that just echos the `<br>` tag. I have also tried to concat the `\n` but it is ignored.

What this is for is an email like system. When the user replies to an email, I want the old message below with a seperator like a few dashes. I can't get this to work though.

```
new message starts here

--------------
old message here
```

Can someone please give a hand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a return character: `\r`

According to [this article](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=162804), the `\n` newline character should work. What is happening when you are inserting the `\n` character into the string using double quotes?

This works for me:

```
 <textarea>test
testing</textarea>
```

it properly creates the next line. Check to make sure your source code looks something like that, with n actual line break in the source where you want it to be.

Comment: Do you get anything at all? Is it displaying in the textarea?

Comment: Well, nothing happens when I insert the newline character. Now, I'm using trim() on that variable and I'm wondering if that may have something to do with it.

Comment: No, the \r and \n are not displaying at all.

Comment: Trim gets rid of new lines in and other empty space variables at the front and back of the string. This string will be trimmed `test\n` to `test`, this won't: `test \n test`

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I just removed the trim function but it is still doing the exact same thing. I'm stumped.

Comment: Could you show me some source code? It would be easier to debug.

Comment: $message = "\r\r------".$vals['message']; is what I'm using

Comment: `$message = "\r\n\r\n-----".$vals['message'];`

Comment: Try replacing those \r with \n, and then do you do anything else to the variables. (You should have already taken out the trim).

Comment: `"\r\r"` means nothing to any modern system. `"\n\n"` should probably work though. `"\r\n\r\n"` will work anywhere though.

Comment: Chacha, I got it, thank you very much! I have a "create" method that I forgot about that also had trim() removing the newline character. The problem was that I was testing this within the "reply" method and was why I couldn't see the results. :/